# aⁿbⁿcⁿdⁿ using 2-stack PDA

Tags: context-free, pushdown-automata

I need to construct a PDA using 2 stacks for accepting the language $L = \{a^nb^nc^nd^n | $ $n \geq 0\}$.

Pushing $a$'s to first stack and $b$'s to second and poping them for corresponding $c$'s and $d$'s respectively won't work because that would mean number of $a$'s $= $number of $c$'s and number of $b$'s$ =$ number of $d$'s. I can't come up with an accurate solution.

Comment: Hint: Push $a$s on first stack for each $a$, pop $a$ from first stack for each $b$ and simultaneously push $a$s to second stack. Can you proceed from here?

Comment: @ttnick hey! thank you! Yes, I can proceed from here. I will pop second stack a's for every c and add c's to the first stack simultaneously and then pop them all for d's. :D

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40317006/pushdown-automaton-pda-for-l-anbncnn-1#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40317006/pushdown-automaton-pda-for-l-anbncnn-1#_=_) or check the answer below.

2 stack PDA to recognize the language {an bn cn dn n>=0} for this we should follow the given steps:

Use the first stack for checking an bn, this can be done by pushing a whenever you see an a and then popping a when you see a b.

Use the second stack for checking bn cn  this can be done by pushing b whenever you see a b and then popping b when you see a c.

Use the first stack for checking cn dn  this can be done by pushing c whenever you see a c and then popping c when you see a d.

Accept if both stacks are empty at the end of this process, otherwise do not accept it.

Let ^ and z be the stack symbol of stack 1 and 2 respectively, then the transition diagram of the above PDA will be as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A 2-stack nondeterministic PDA is easily shown to be equivalent to a nondeterministic Turing machine—just use the two stacks as the left and right halves of the tape. So you could just write a Turing machine that accepts the language and then convert that to a 2-stack PDA.

Not as elegant as [ttnick's](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/107152#comment229696_107152)/[Devharsh Trivedi's](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/121319/8311) solution, perhaps, but it avoids having to be clever with stack management.